# The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (...)

Tags: java, string, format

Here is my code:

```
int hoursFormat = 1, minsFormat = 2, secsFormat = 3;
String timeFormat = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hoursFormat, minsFormat, secsFormat);
```

This gives a compilation error:

```
Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the 
      arguments (String, int, int, int)
```

Why am I getting this error here and how can I fix it?

Comment: What JDK make/version are you using? What IDE are you using? What's the IDE project's Java compliance level version set to?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? If you are using an IDE such as Eclipse, what compliance level is the Java compiler set at? **Edit:** Too slow! Dang you Balus! :)

Comment: The compliance level--I'll bet that's it.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem with printf. I am using JDK 1.6.0_27. Setting the compliance level to 1.6 solved my issue. This can be set in the following way.

Project > Properties > Java Compiler

You can also refer to the following thread:

[Why am I getting a compilation errors with a simple printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774428/why-am-i-getting-a-compilation-errors-with-a-simple-printf)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Java version 1.4 or below? [Autoboxing](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/basic_types/autoboxing.html) wasn't introduced until Java 5. Try manually boxing `int`s to `Integer`s.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using eclipse?

If so sometimes, issues like this appear, when everything seems to be correct. Here is how I just solved it:

- Right click on project and go to properties->Java Compiler
- You would be seeing a recent Compiler compliance level (1.7 in my case) set in the drop down ("compiler compliance level"). Also same version is seen set below in "Generated .class files compatibility" and "Source compatibility".

Now:

- Select the Checkbox: "Use default compliance settings"
- Notice that a lower version (in my case 1.1) got set for: "Generated .class files compatibility" and "Source compatibility". This is the issue, although eclipse is showing that it is compiling using a higher compiler it is not.
- In the drop down "compiler compliance level" choose some other level and then select the one you want. The changes would be reflected below in "Generated .class files compatibility" and "Source compatibility".

This should have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have `jdk 1.4` or below version. The method String.format() is introduce in `Jdk 1.5`.

Take a look at [coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/403327/java/java/String-format) post.

Comment: The method `format(String, Object[])` doesn't exist in 1.4 at all, it would have resulted in a completely different compilation error.

Comment: If that were true, the error would go more like "The method format(String, int, int, int) is undefined for the type String. This error indicates that the method is recognized but the args are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna vote for a clean build. There's no reason it should be failing like this, especially when you try manually boxing to Integer. Are you using Eclipse? Sometimes it gets confused, and you just have to rebuild everything.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of format is:

```
public static String format(String format, Object ... args) {
    return new Formatter().format(format, args).toString();
    }
```

and it seems no any mistakes in your code, for my suggestion try to run this with console application without using any IDE (For test purpose).