# Unable to compile using Java 1.7 in Jetbrains Intellij after moving from 1.6 to 1.7 (maven based project)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javac

Using Jetbrains 11.2 project based on a Maven project. Then I required to move to 1.7. I have 1.7 installed , I updated my pom.xml and I can rebuild the whole package using maven okay.

I've modified every setting I can see in Intelli Projects settings regarding Java version

- Project SDk
- Project language Level
- Modules Languages/Sources/Language Level
- Modules Languages/Dependencies/Module SDK

but I cannot get it to compile a file it complains:

```
Error:javac target release of 1.6 conflicts with source release 1.7
```

I then tried on my other dev machine using the same codebase but a different Intellij Project and on this I get a similar error:

```
Error:javac: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7
```

I cannot see anything else to change in order to get this working.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Doh, found it

File/Settings/Java Compiler/Additional command line parameters

changed from **-target 1.6** to **-target 1.7**

Does seem wierd for it to be here though, disconnected from the rest of the related options.

Comment: These options are added when importing from Maven.

Answer (score 13):

As an alternative solution, which worked for me is to check in **Module Settings** the 
**Language Level** property. It was set to `8.0 Lambdas` and changed to `6.0 @Overrides in interfaces`, and after that compilation worked without error.

Answer (score 9):

## **IntelliJ 2017 (also 15 or 2016)**

You can change compiler version here:

```
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler
```

Now change `Target bytecode version` to desired one.

## **IntelliJ 13 or 14**

You can change compiler version here:

```
 Intellij IDEA -> Preferences -> Compiler -> Java Compiler
 -> Project bytecode version -> 1.7 (for example)
```

Comment: Similar problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900373/idea-javac-source-release-1-7-requires-target-release-1-7

Answer (score 7):

For IntelliJ 12, I solved this by opening the File:Project Structure and updating the Project SDK to 1.7 and the Project language level to "7.0 - Diamonds, ARM, multi-catch etc."

If you don't have IntelliJ configured with JDK 1.7, add it with the "New" button. Select type "JDK".

Answer (score 1):

Another potential fix is to make sure that your build file has the version hardcoded as seen here

```
    <javac target="1.7" source="1.7" ... />
```

as opposed to

```
<property name="java.version" value="1.7" />
<javac target="${java.version}" source="${java.version}" ... />
```

Though this could be due to my misunderstanding of how variables work in build files. You would think that this would make sense though

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. 
I solved it by  Intellij IDEA -> Preferences -> Compiler -> Java Compiler
 -> Project bytecode version -> 1.7 & Target bytecode version -> 1.7