# javacTask: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7

Tags: android, scala, sbt

I have setup an Android project through sbt (0.13.1) in IDEA 13.0.2.  It is mixed Java 7 and Scala 2.10.3.  It uses the SBT support in IDEA.

Even though in my build.sbt I have the following:

```
 scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.7"

 javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")
```

here is the result when I make the project with IDEA:

```
 java: javacTask: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7
```

Any help please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900373/idea-javac-source-release-1-7-requires-target-release-1-7 relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved.

You need this:

```
javacOptions in Compile <<= (javacOptions in Compile) map { _ collect {
        case "1.5" => "1.7"
        case s     => s
    }
}
```

I suppose that this is due to the fact, that the default javacOptions supplied by the plugin is 1.5, and adding the setting doesn't work, but replacing it.