# Compiling Android project with JDK 1.7

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea, android-maven-plugin

My Android project is set up to use Maven, so I imported into IntelliJ from the pom.xml file. The compiler settings in IntelliJ are correctly pointing to 1.7, but when I try to compile I get:

> Error: java: javacTask: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7

My settings for the maven compiler plugin has both source and target set to this, so that's not the problem. However, in the module settings I see that my module is using

> Maven Android API 19 Platform (java version "1.6.0_37")

If I try changing this manually in IntelliJ when I open my project after closing it it gets set back. I think that it has something to do with the [android-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/), but I don't see where to force it to use java 1.7.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12900373/435605

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the Android Maven Plugin that forces Java 6. It must have to do IntelliJ and its Maven integration somehow. Or some other related configuration.