# lambda expression code is showing compilation error in Intellj

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, compilation, java-8

this code is copied from a reference but it shows compilation error in Intellj:

```
Stream locales = Stream.of(Locale.getAvailableLocales());
            Map<String, Set<String>> countryToLanguages = locales.collect(
                    groupingBy(l -> l.getDisplayCountry(),
                            mapping(l -> l.getDisplayLanguage(),
                                    toSet())));
```

the compiler is seeing object named "l" and a java Object not as a locale; so it cann't understand the methods l.getDisplayCountry() and l.getDisplayLanguage().

also the Project SDK is java 8 and project language level is 8- lambdas, type annotations etc.

Comment: You are using a raw type, it should be `Stream<Locale> locales`.

Comment: Or just don’t store streams in local variables at all. There’s no benefit in doing that, it only open the possibility to accidentally using a Stream twice. Further, if you have an array rather than varargs, prefer `Arrays.stream` over `Stream.of`: `Map<String, Set<String>> countryToLanguages = Arrays.stream(Locale.getAvailableLocales()).collect( groupingBy(l -> l.getDisplayCountry(), mapping(l -> l.getDisplayLanguage(), toSet())));`

Comment: By the way, you can use method reference, then, there is no variable `l` to worry about  its type: `Map<String, Set<String>> countryToLanguages = Arrays.stream( Locale.getAvailableLocales())
.collect( groupingBy(Locale::getDisplayCountry, mapping(Locale::getDisplayLanguage, toSet())));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @AlexisC. yes, i wrote this part and forget to specify the stream type.

Comment: @AlexisC. i think this question is about fixing a compilation problem not about the general rule of raw type. do you still think it's a duplicate/

Comment: If you understand what a raw type is (which the duplicate is about), you'll understand why you have this compilation problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In intellij, You need to set Language Level (8) for each module as well.
Project Structure -> Module -> Select Module -> Sources -> Language Level = 8

And if you want to change in POM directly

First- Add Properties

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

second- Add Plugin

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Got from, thanks to Anuj
[stop IntelliJ IDEA to switch java language level everytime the pom is reloaded (or change the default project language level)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037657/stop-intellij-idea-to-switch-java-language-level-everytime-the-pom-is-reloaded)