# Build failing due to version only via terminal

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a simple maven project which builds fine and runs in Intellij. The Java version is set to version 8 under relevant settings in Intellij.

Under the maven POM file, I have set the following to point to the java version.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <javac.src.version>1.8</javac.src.version>
        <javac.target.version>1.8</javac.target.version>
    </properties>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>exa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
    .....
```

My maven version and info as follows:

```
Maven home: C:\Users\name\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_231, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre
```

As mentioned, no issues when run via Intellij. But when I run maven commands via the intellij terminal or normal terminal, I get following error.

Example Maven commands.

```
mvn clean package
or
mvn verify
```

Error:

```
COMPILATION ERROR
/C:/Users/name/projectname/src/main/java/pack/Main.java:[17,51] method references are not supported in -source 1.5
```

I don't even have java sdk 1.5 on my machine. Can I get some help on where I should change this version to 8 so I can make a maven build please? Thanks.

Comment: Hope it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037657/stop-intellij-idea-to-switch-java-language-level-every-time-the-pom-is-reloaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project's pom.xml, it seems the source is configured to java 1.5. Make sure the correct source version is configured in `pom.xml`.

If you are using maven-compiler-plugin, change the version as below.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```