# Continuously getting the java: invalid source release: 1.9 error when compiling

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I have attempted to fix this problem using the various forums on this site, but nothing has helped. I tried similar techniques as used to fix other people's 1.8 errors, but nothing has worked. I have my java class file under my source folder and no imports, I just simply want a basic output message to make sure intelliJ is working as it should. Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: where is your code? Please add some code to understand the issue.

Comment: Go to file -> settings -> Build Execution and Deployment -> Java -> Compiler
Here change the compiler language level to 1.8 or lesser.

Comment: Did you check all the options in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891)? Are you sure it doesn't help?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here change the language level to 1.8 or lesser. This changes the target release version.

> Go to file -> settings -> Build Execution and Deployment -> Java -> Compiler

Here change the language level to 1.8 or lesser. This changes the source release version.

> File -> Project Structure -> Module Settings -> Tab: Source: Language
>   Level

and also here,

> File -> Project Structure -> Project(In left pane) -> Project language level

Comment: Are you aware that it changes the `target` version, not the `source`?

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I have edited the answer - To refer both source and target release version

Comment: Nice Complete answer <3

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone stumbles onto the same problem and the above answer doesn't solve it, my issue was resolved doing the following (I was using Gradle):

1. Open the *your-project-name*.**ipr** file.
2. Verify the following line:

`<bytecodeTargetLevel target="1.xx" />`

Mine was set to `1.10`. I changed it to `1.08` (which my project SDK was set to) and the problem was solved.