# Error:java: invalid source release: 11 when attempting to run JavaFX IntelliJ

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

Using JavaFX with the language set to 8 I am able to run my project, however when the language is set to 11 I receive the error *Error:java: invalid source release: 11* I cannot find any other news on this error on the internet, and the steps I followed were consistent with https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ for non-modular IntelliJ JavaFX. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280859/intellij-idea-error-java-invalid-source-release-1-9)? Review your project settings.

Comment: Switching the project level to 8 does fix my issue, however the starting guide specifies that the language level can be set to 11.