# error: invalid source release 14 with --enable-preview

Tags: java, intellij-idea, micronaut

I am using Micronaut2.0.2 application with IntelliJ IDE 2020.2.2. I have enabled the preview feature in from the language level in IDE

[image]

And in the Gradle file I have the below option

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('14')
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('14')
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    options.compilerArgs.addAll([
            '-parameters',
            // enables incremental compilation
            '-Amicronaut.processing.incremental=true',
            '-Amicronaut.processing.annotations=fete.bird.*',
            "-Amicronaut.processing.group=$project.group",
            "-Amicronaut.processing.module=$project.name",
            "--enable-preview"
    ])
}
```

Getting an error as `error: invalid source release 14 with --enable-preview`

Comment: Have you tried the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156370/errorjava-error-invalid-source-release-13-using-jdk12-with-intellij)?

Comment: Yes I did still same issue

Comment: First - I do not understand why do you set Language Level to 15 preview for the module but use 14 in Gradle build. Second: you must not modify any build settings (source/target, dependencies etc) in IDE UI in case of the Gradle project. You should only configure it in Gradle build files. Have you modified any other build options for project? Do you use **IntelliJ IDEA** or **Gradle** for the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Build and run using**. Does it work if you build project from command line using Gradle?

Comment: I have reproduced this when I have 15 JDK set for project - which is used for compilation. When I set it to 14 JDK it works.

Comment: When we create a Micronaut project, the java version is 14. But when we want to use the preview features, we need to add the 15 previews in the IntelliJ IDE. I haven't change any build configuration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [intellij idea - Error: java: invalid source release 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280859/intellij-idea-error-java-invalid-source-release-1-9)

Comment: It has nothing to do with ´preview´, This is intellij ERROR. You need to set jvm in Intellij preference, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280859/intellij-idea-error-java-invalid-source-release-1-9/68859868

Answer (score 6):

Set Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Gradle JVM** to 14 JDK version.

Comment: If I set to 14 version, I won't be able to use the preview feature, currently I have oracle open jdk 15

Comment: I don't have installed JDK 14. I have 15. I have the same setup for spring boot application and it working fine

Comment: `If I set to 14 version, I won't be able to use the preview feature` but you set the language level to 14 in your build.gradle file. How do you want to use features from 15 then?

Comment: In the whole world of this question in SO, this was the only answer mentioning the right thing to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have some wrong configurations in your `pom.xml` like this remove it. It worked for me after I remove the configs:

```xml
    <configuration>
        <source>15</source>
        <target>15</target>
        <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
```

That's what was messing up for me. Since I already have Java 16 already.