# An unexpected error has occured: java: error: invalid source release: 17

Tags: java, compiler-errors

java: error: invalid source release: 17

I keep getting this error when I run my Intellji Programme. I have tried pretty much everything like changing the versions as an example. This Error came when I updated my software, as the IDE advised me to, but as soon as I did this happened. I have attached a few screenshots below if anybody can help!

[This is the picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQdB2.png)
[This is what I tried doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hTwV.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [intellij idea - Error: java: invalid source release 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280859/intellij-idea-error-java-invalid-source-release-1-9)