# Gradle build fails through Terminal but is successful in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, intellij-idea, build, compiler-errors

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

> error: invalid source release: 17

I have spent more than 5-6 hours fixing this issue. Due to this i am not able to run my application. Please help me out so that i can proceed

update: I am able to create build successfully in eclipse. but now it is failing with error
Error: Could not find or load main class com.abc.ABCServiceApp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.ABCServiceApp

and build is still failing through terminal with the same error
C:\Users\user\Documents\abc\def\xyzservice>gradle build

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

> error: invalid source release: 17

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date

Update: i want to run this project usinh openJDK-15
C:\Users\user1>java -version
openjdk version "15" 2020-09-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15+36-1562)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15+36-1562, mixed mode, sharing)

Update:
i think below is the problem. i want to run my application with java 15, but it is set to java 17, i tried changing it back to 15, but it again get set to 17
[image]

Update: lost my patience. Installed another eclipse and it workimg now

Comment: You have an invalid source language level set.  Check or post your build.gradle

Comment: I can  not post that because of security reason

Comment: Does it work *outside* of the IDEs?

Comment: Post at least "targetCompatibility" and "sourceCompatibility" of your build.gradle and this IDE settings: https://i.imgur.com/aGd1Ynz.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ - Invalid source release: 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69696321/intellij-invalid-source-release-17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a IDE issue, somehow it was picking Java17 even though after setting it to 15. Thank you all for your reply. It helped at least to know the root cause. I uninstalled the eclipse and re-installed a fresh one. It works now