# Tell IntelliJ to compile as Java 8 source code rather than Java 1.5

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

After importing into IntelliJ 2017.1 RC a simple Maven project created with the [Quickstart archetype](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/), I get compiler errors because IntelliJ insists on compiling as Java 1.5 code.

- I have only a Java 8 Update 121 JDK  installed on my Mac (macOS Sierra).

[image]

- I verified that `File` > `Project Structure` > `Project` > `Project SDK`  is set to `1.8 (java version "1.8.0_121")`.
- I verified that `File` > `Project Structure` > `Project` > `Project language level`  is set to `8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.`.

[image: screenshot of IntelliJ Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler panel]

- I changed `Preferences` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` > `Java Compiler` > `Project bytecode version` to `1.8` from blank.
- I changed `Preferences` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` > `Java Compiler` > `Per-module bytecode version` to `1.8` from `1.5` in my single list item (named with my package name).

And…

- I chose menu item `Build` > `Build Project`.
- I chose menu item `Build` > `Recompile`.
- I chose menu item `Build` > `Rebuild Project`.

Yet I continue to get error messages related to misinterpreting Java 8 code as Java 5 code, such as:

> Error:(28, 113) java: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.5
>
> (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)

What else must I do to convince IntelliJ that my code should be compiled as Java 8 code rather than as Java 5 code?

Comment: You have changed the `target` version, `source` version is configured elsewhere, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891).

Comment: Yes, that fixed it: Change `File` > `Project Structure` > `Project settings` > `Modules` > `Sources` (tab) > `Language Level` from `5.0 'enum' keyword, generics, autoboxing, etc.` to `8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.`

Comment: As a prophylactic, add these 4 lines to your POM before importing into IntelliJ: `<properties> <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source> <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> </properties>` per [this Maven page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).