# Compiler issue with intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation

I am new to programming and have compiler issue with Intellij idea it says :

`"Error:java: invalid source release: 1.9."`

Could any one help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IDEA: javac: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900373/idea-javac-source-release-1-7-requires-target-release-1-7)

Answer (score 1):

Seems your IDE is looking for JDK 9 and you are compiling your code with different version.

**Solution:** Go to, Menubar --> File --> Project Stricture --> Project Settings --> Project

Check if you have any SDK(other than 1.9) installed in your system. If found, then select it.

**Project Language:** Select the same. click on Apply and OK. Rebuild your code and errors are gone

If no SDK found then download last version of JDK from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html) and point IntelliJ to it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to compile with a java version that is not java9, and your IDE is looking for java9 in the settings.

You will have to change the `SDK` version within **IntelliJ** - see [Configuring Global, Project and Module SDKs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html)