# IntelliJ: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-runtime-compiler

I'm running a Java Maven project on IntelliJ, and I make sure that this project will be compiled by Java 1.8.

I set JRE to version 8 in Run/Debug Configuration
[image]

and also in Project Structure: 
[image]
My pom.xml file also includes java version 8 by the following:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I also set Java compiler option to version 1.8.[image]

When I run the project, I get an error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile
>   (default-compile) on project feed_matcher: Fatal error compiling:
>   invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]

Do you know how to resolve this issue?

P.S I followed this link: [IDEA: javac: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900373/idea-javac-source-release-1-7-requires-target-release-1-7) and I still couldn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Is it a Maven project? Then make sure that in the `pom.xml` there isn't a setting that says it should use Java 8.

Comment: IntelliJ still tries to compile Java 8 code (and the Java 7 compiler complains).   Double check the compiler settings too.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, how can I check it in IntelliJ? I already showed project structure

Comment: If it is a maven project, you may have done the compiler configuration incorrectly in the pom.xml.  Can you run "mvn clean install" from the command line having JAVA_HOME Pointing to your Java 7 installation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IDEA: javac: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900373/idea-javac-source-release-1-7-requires-target-release-1-7)

Answer (score 4):

I assume you *want* to have it in version 8, despite so many comments telling you to set to 7.

You probably missed the setting for the maven runner, this is under *Preferences -> Build, Exection, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Runner*, see attached image. You need to set that to Java 8 as well.
[image: config screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Look in Build Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler

Then look for per module bytecode version

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure JAVA_HOME is set to JDK7 or JRE7. This is explained in the
  following [link](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)
- Make sure that you open a new shell an run intellij
- If this doesnt work, look at at the idea.bat file which is used to run intellij - make sure it uses jdk7/jre7
- Make sure the JDKs are defined properly in your project. Look at this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/defining-a-jdk-and-a-mobile-sdk-in-intellij-idea.html) for more information.
- Make sure that the source is defined as 1.7 at maven

The above 4 steps always helped me to troubleshoot such issues.

Comment: 1. done.
2. a new shell? I use Windows. I restarted my machine, and it still didn't help.
3. idea.bat? Where is it located?
4. done. 
5. done.

Comment: New shell at Windows = new Window.
Windows also has shell :)
Do you have JDK8 installed on your machine? (or JRE8) ?

Comment: Sure. Of Course