# Solving persistent invalid target release issue in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Sorry for being a bother, but ever since yesterday, I've had issues with IntelliJ not working. Every time I try to run maven build, it always says the same error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project HelloWorld: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: \1.8 -> [Help 1]
```

I tried searching up similar questions on here, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137286/error-java-invalid-target-release-11-intellij-idea), but the issue for that OP is his IntelliJ is outdated. For reference, I'm using IntelliJ 2019. Furthermore, everything was working last week and the week before, I have no idea what might've caused IntelliJ to suddenly throw me that error.

I've also tried following the steps taken by the OP and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231757/intellij-fatal-error-compiling-invalid-target-release-1-8), to no avail. I set the Java compiler option to both 1.8 and 12, to no avail, and went to maven runner to set the JRE to JDK 12, without working.

At this point, I am truly frustrated with IntelliJ and can't tell if I'm being dumb. Anything would be helpful.

Here are my "settings"
[image]

Note for both bytecode versions, I have experimented with 12 and 1.8. Both produce the same output.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `\1.8` looks suspicious. Did you specify the option with the slash somewhere in `pom.xml` or in the IDE? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891

Comment: @CrazyCoder I doubt it, pom.xml gives this for 1.8: <java.version>1.8</java.version>. Can you elaborate on your second question, the \1.8 in the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the options:

[image: typo]

Must be `1.8` instead of `\1.8`.

Comment: I'm still having the issue. I removed the forward slash and ran maven build. Still brought up the same error on invalid target release...

Comment: Check your pom.xml for the same typo.

Comment: Well, it worked now. Turns out I had to remove the slashes in the code <source>${java.version}</source> and <target>${java.version}</target>. Is there any reason why IntelliJ might've added the slashes? It was working a week ago, I am baffled