# How to change Java version for decompiled bytecode in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to view the decompiled bytecode for a Java 8 class in IntelliJ but when opening it up it is trying to decompile the class using bytecode version Java 6:

[image]

I have managed to open it using Java 8 in the past (not sure how) but I have no idea how to change settings in IntelliJ to open it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Run `javap` on your `.class` file to confirm that it really targets Java 8. It looks like it was compiled with `-target 1.6`.

Comment: Ah I just went to find the .class file in my external libraries and when I pick the class from there it correctly decompiles it with Java 8. It's only when I ctrl+click the class in my project that it tries to use Java 6 for some reason..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies I realise I did something very silly. The class En I have imported was not the correct Java 8 one. :(