# diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5 even when compiler version is 1.8

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javacompiler

When packaging my project using maven in intellij idea, it gives below error, also my java compiler version is set on 1.8:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
I'm really confused, because both java version and compiler version are set with 1.8.

Comment: It looks that you have the correct version in maven or Gradle but in your module settings is set to a lower version or vice-versa. Please check Module settings compiler version and your pom.xml or build.gradle

Comment: `-source 1.5` means "only support language features from Java 1.5", no matter the compiler version

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Include the following within your `<build>` tag of your `pom.xml` to configure maven to compile with source and target with Java `1.8` :

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```