# How to revert settings in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project within IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.1 that was using Java 1.7.  I wanted to use a maven plugin that required Java 1.8, so I changed various Java settings in Intellij IDEA.

```
File -> Settings
    Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler
MyModule -> Open Module Settings
    Project Structure window, [Project Settings -> Modules] Dependencies tab 
    Project Structure window, [Project Settings -> Project] Project SDK and Project language level
```

IntelliJ IDEA has a really nice feature of keeping a "local history" when one changes source files in the editor.  It would be nice if they kept a history for their settings files, or if they maintained backup settings files.

I can't find such a feature.  When I look at the `.idea` directory containing the files that keep the setting information, e.g., `misc.xml` and `compiler.xml`, I don't see any backup files.

Does IntelliJ provide any way to backup to older settings?  If not, I suppose I should get in the habit of making backup copies myself.  But shouldn't modern development tools protect me from myself?  ;)

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - Thanks, that is helpful for knowing the places where the compiler version might be set.  My question is really a more general one - after having made changes to settings, how can you revert back to prior settings?  (Basically, almost like version control for settings, although a simple back up file would be a step in the right direction.)

Comment: You can actually manage your IDE settings via Git, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html. However, the projects settings stored in .idea directory are not shared that way, since they are per project, you can commit them to your project version control, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839.