# Local Variable Type Inference not being recognized

Tags: java, intellij-idea, var, java-10

I installed JDK 10 to try out the new features, and I got a big hung up on `var` - for some reason, even though the JDK was added to IntelliJ (version 2018.1), the following code still won't compile, saying Java cannot find the symbol `var`:

```
public class Variations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var local = "foo";
        System.out.println(local);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here, or is there an option in IntelliJ I should enable?

EDIT: Both *project* and *module* SDK and Language Level are set to the Java 10 installation and lvl. 10 (though not the `X - experimental` level).

Comment: Check that JDK 10 is used for the project and all the modules. Language level should be also set to 10 for all the modules, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891 for the relevant screenshots.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Unfortunately those are all good - that was my first thought as well (and I did have to change them), but a Rebuild didn't help either.
I'll add this to the question, though, since it's a valid point.

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. Delete IDE configuration (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) and set up JDK from scratch. Share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if the issue persists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, though a hard restart of the IDE is not enough, by setting language level to `X - Experimental features` on both the project and the module once, then re-setting it to lvl. 10 *was* enough to bring the IDE back in line.

I guess I should credit @CrazyCoder here for giving me the idea, even if indirectly.

Answer (score 3):

In Settings/Build/Compiler/Java Compiler you must change the "Target bytecode version" to 10 in each one of your modules.

Comment: Explaining why he should do that can also be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I did. Apparently, I had to up the language level _beyond_ 10 then lower it back once, and that brought the IDE back in line.

Answer (score 1):

I searched on the web for a while and I found out that IntelliJ fully supports it. Have you checked if the SDK version you are running on IntelliJ is the 10th?
You can check it by going to **Project Structure** (*Alt+Shift+Ctrl+S*), **SDKS**. From here if you don't see the label *10.0* in the left side of the panel just manually add it with the plus button.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely, I have it set as the Project SDK, and I have the language level set to 10 as well - by all accounts and reasoning, it *should* support it, and this code *should* compile. Hence my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with Java10 on my [MacOS IntelliJ 2018.1](https://download-cf.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIC-2018.1.dmg) built on **March 27 2018**.

> IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (Community Edition)
>   Build #IC-181.4203.550, built on March 27, 2018

There might be error with either your IntelliJ or `JDK`. Try to use `jshell` from terminal instead. If can, should update your IntelliJ. If cannot, should check your installed `JDK`. The version on my machine:

> "10" 2018-03-20
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)