# Intellij IDEA 2018.1 Jdk10 cannot run test

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Cannot run test with IDEA 2018.1 + JDK 10. It says:

> Error:(6, 1) java: modules are not supported in -source 8   (use
>   -source 9 or higher to enable modules)

I've raised language level up to 10 using menus:

*File->Project Structure -> Project -> Project Language Level 10*

*File->Project Structure -> Modules{each module} -> Language Level 10*

but it didn't help.

What can be reason of the error?

Comment: Make sure you've checked all the places where the language level is set per http://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891. If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you go to `module-info.java`, put cursor on the module name and press Alt+Enter, is there an option to set the right language level?

Comment: It didn't help. For now, I rolled back to jdk8

Comment: did you try changing root project's source and cleaning the cache of IDEA?

Comment: which build tool you are using?

Comment: If using maven or gradle you can specify source and target jvm versions e.g. in gradle `sourceCompatibility = 1.8` & 
`targetCompatibility = 1.8`

Answer (score 0):

please check what sdk you are using locally as below:

[image]