# Intellij Error:(3, 4) java: modules are not supported in -source 8 (use -source 9 or higher to enable modules)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9, java-module

Edit - this is solved - the issue was solved by setting: "Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment - Java Compiler -> Project Bytecode Version : 9"

I'm following the example/tutorial at https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/modules/getting-started-in-intellij.html

This is NOT a maven project. I have set the source level to 9 in the project structure eg

[image]

I have set the project level to 9:

[image]

I am getting "Error:(3, 4) java: modules are not supported in -source 8
  (use -source 9 or higher to enable modules)" error when trying to build/run the project's main class.

And yes I have seen [Intellij IDEA 2018.1 Jdk10 cannot run test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50680791/intellij-idea-2018-1-jdk10-cannot-run-test) which is unanswered.

I have just updated Intellij to 2019.2.4 but the issue remains. I am using SDK 11. 
How can this be fixed? Thanks.

**Edit:** the Run/Debug configuration options:

[image]

**Edit:** the error:

[image]

**Edit:** the platform SDK:

[image]

**Edit:** the dependencies panel:

[image]

FWIW, the contents of the iml files show language level 9:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_9" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_9" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="common.widgets" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: Check the configuration that is used for building / running. You should have an "edit configuration" button somewhere on the top bar near the run button. Check if the SDK and parameters used there are ok.

Comment: Thanks but (under the "Application" dropdown on the LHS pane) there's no SDK option; there is a JRE option and it's set to "Default (11 - SDK of 'data.widget' module).

Comment: Where do you see that error?

Comment: In the Messages pane at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Can you check the Dependencies tab in "Project Structure > Modules"? You can set the module SDK there.

Comment: The Dependencies says the Module SDK is the Project SDK (11). I will paste a screenshot to the question.

Comment: That's a bummer :( Have you tried to restart with invalidating the cache? I have found this option to help in some weird scenarios. Also are you able to compile the project from the command line? Just to be sure it's an IntelliJ issue.

Comment: Let me try that now...although I had to restart when I upgraded Intellij..

Comment: Sorry, no dice...Invalidated and restarted but still, getting the same error.

Answer (score 9):

This is solved - the issue was solved by setting: "Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment - Java Compiler -> Project Bytecode Version : 9"

Thanks to all who gave their time to try to help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Set SDK]

I think you must be setting **SDK** under **Platform Setting** in **project structure**

[image]

Comment: No, I have 11 there (as well as 8). I append/paste the screenshot to the question.

Comment: No!  you haven't put snapshot of SDK. what you have shared is project settings

Comment: Also, can you do a java -version on your intellij terminal?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your statement.  In any case, I think you can see that I have set everything everywhere in Intellij at least to either 9 or 11.  But as for java -version in the Terminal window in intellij, that reports version 8: `$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"...`

Comment: Can you change terminal version to 11 ? I know this shouldn't be the case but just to see if it works

Comment: Hi Vinay, I understand where you're coming from but  I'm at work and we use Java 8; I really don't want to start messing with my Java version on my linux terminal by changing symlinks and environment variables.  And in any case I can use Java 9 language features without getting red highlighting (syntax errors/unrecognized keywords such as "module", "requires" and "exports") so I think this should not be the cause.