# JavaFX error: Class file has wrong version 54, should be 52

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I got java JDK 11 installed and I am using the Maven JavaFX. But when I try and run the code I get a build error which is "class file has wrong version 54, should be 52"

**POM.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You're compiling with target version 8, but your dependencies are compiled with target version 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using Java 11 for compilation and the **language level** is set to 10 or higher. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891) for the details how to configure the language level in IntelliJ IDEA for Maven.