# IntelliJ - What indicates that a module is compiling in the Java version indicated in the POM

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, compilation, maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin

Using a multi-module Maven project configured in IntelliJ IDEA, I am configuring version 1.8 in the maven-compiler-plugin in the parent POM  version. But I am configuring 1.5 in a certain child module.

In the parent:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

In the child:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In Eclipse, I had this indicator:

[image: How Eclipse indicates the compiler version for a module]

How and/or where do we check that in IntelliJ IDEA? How do I know that the child module is compiling with the desired 1.5 Java version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891) for the relevant screenshots.

You can find the source version in the Project Structure dialog, Modules, Sources tab: Language level.

Target version is in File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler (Per-module bytecode version).