# Intellij Gradle: 'cannot find symbol' for var - Java 11.0.4

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

While trying to build my application using features from Java 11 (var), I keep getting the error message explaining 
'cannot find symbol: var ex = new ClassName();
symbol: class var'

I'm using IntelliJ 2019.2.1 Community and Oracle Java 11.0.4, I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900373/idea-javac-source-release-1-7-requires-target-release-1-7/12900859#12900859) but it seems to be a solution for Maven, but not for Gradle.

I expect, since I set the JDK version to 11 and the Language Level to 11 to just work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Please add some code the issue occurs for to clarify your question.

Answer (score 5):

Add `sourceCompatibility = '11'` to your `build.gradle` file, and refresh gradle in IDEA.

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Comment: @AwlsomeAlex could you please accept the answer

Comment: @MaxFarsikov actually it doesn't work... I have 100 errors of Java symbols on Gradle 7.2 and Java 11.