# Has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk

I get this problem using [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA). But I have the newest version of everything newly installed on my system.

```
... has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime
(class file version 57.0), this version of the Java Runtime only
recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I've set:

- `PATH` as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13`
- `JAVA_HOME` as: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13`
- `JRE_HOME` as: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221`

I've set the path, and I tried to find a change in the Project structure.

#### Complete error message

```
H:\087-JAVA\HelloWorld\src>java com.codewithmosh.Main
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/codewithmosh/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What happens when you run `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin\java com.codewithmosh.Main`?

Comment: See the answer below. If removing the [highlighted path](https://i.imgur.com/bXhEiFC.png) followed by the reboot helps, feel free to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Had same issue with Eclipse. I have openJDK8 (aka java 1.8; also includes JRE) installed. In eclipse I had selected JRE OpenJDK8 to be used but did not realize I had to set the compiler separately. In preferences > Java > Compiler > Compiler compliance level -> 1.8

Comment: "...compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime" didn't know the runtime could *compile* things, I thought that was what the compiler did, silly me...

Answer (score 78):

The easiest solution is to change the Java version in your IDE. In Intellij, go to File --> Project Structure and change the Project SDK to the one that is supported by your Java Runtime (in your case it's 52 which corresponds to version 8 or less). Here's a table that shows the mapping between Java SE Version and Major Version:

| Java SE | Major version |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0.2 | 45 |
| 1.1 | 45 |
| 1.2 | 46 |
| 1.3 | 47 |
| 1.4 | 48 |
| 5.0 | 49 |
| 6 | 50 |
| 7 | 51 |
| 8 | 52 |
| 9 | 53 |
| 10 | 54 |
| 11 | 55 |
| 12 | 56 |
| 13 | 57 |
| 14 | 58 |
| 15 | 59 |
| 16 | 60 |
| 17 | 61 |
| 18 | 62 |
| 19 | 63 |
| 20 | 64 |
| 21 | 65 |

The table is taken from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html

Answer (score 64):

You need to double check the `PATH` environment setting. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13` you currently have there is not correct. Please make sure you have the `bin` subdirectory for the latest JDK version at the top of the `PATH` list.

`java.exe` executable is in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin` directory, so that is what you need to have in `PATH`.

Use [this tool](http://www.rapidee.com/) to quickly verify or edit the environment variables on Windows. It allows to reorder `PATH` entries. It will also highlight invalid paths in red.

If you want your code to run on lower JDK versions as well, change the target bytecode version in the IDE. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891) for the relevant screenshots.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers) for the Java class file versions. What happens is that you build the code with Java 13 and 13 language level bytecode (target) and try to run it with Java 8 which is the first (default) Java version according to the `PATH` variable configuration.

The solution is to have Java 13 `bin` directory in `PATH` or above instead of Java 8. On Windows you may have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` added to `PATH` automatically which points to Java 8 now:

[image: javapath]

If it's the case, remove the highlighted part from `PATH` and then logout/login or reboot for the changes to have effect. You need to **Restrart as administrator** first to be able to edit the System variables (see the button on the top right of the system variables column).

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer. Moving the "Path" of the latest java version up and above any other version in the System Environment variables solves the problem. Be sure to sign in and out, or restart, afterwards

Comment: Don't forget to close and reopen the command line after setting the environment variables. It seems to me a command line window remembers the prev state of the environment variables. (this of course only applies if you're trying to run it from the command line)

Answer (score 43):

This is a setting in IntelliJ IDEA (`$JAVA_HOME` and language level were set to 1.8):

`File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Gradle` > `Gradle JVM`

Select eg. `Project SDK (corretto-1.8)` (or any other compatible version).

Then delete the `build` directory and restart the IDE.

Answer (score 17):

I also encountered similar problem which is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143792/class-file-version-57-0-this-version-of-the-java-runtime-only-recognizes-class?noredirect=1#comment104513928_59143792). The issue was that some applications come with their own JRE and sometimes the installed JDK appears at lower priority level in environment path. Now there are two options:

1. Uninstall the other application which has their own JDK/JRE.
2. Sometimes it is not possible to remove the other application, which was my case. So I moved JDk installed by me to higher priority level in environment path.

[image]

I also removed the path as suggested by @CrazyCoder

Answer (score 17):

I had similar problem with **IntelliJ** when tried to run some Groovy scripts.
Here is how I solved it.

Go to "Project Structure"-> "Project" -> "Project language level" and select "SDK default". This should use the same SDK for all project modules.

Answer (score 8):

How I solved it in Eclipse:

1. go to the properties of the project

   [image]
2. go to Java compiler

   [image]
3. change in the Compiler complicated level to the Java version that my project work with (Java 11 in my project).
   You can see that it your Java that you work when the last message disappear
4. Apply

   [image]

Answer (score 7):

I was facing same problem when I installed JRE by Oracle and solved this problem after my research.

I moved the environment path
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` below `H:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin`

Like this:

Path

`H:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin`
 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`

OR

Path

`%JAVA_HOME%`
`%JRE_HOME%`

Answer (score 5):

I got the problem after an upgrade to java 17. Then I was running the older Run/Debug configuration and needed to update the path to the JDK

[image]

Comment: This is under the Run menu, Edit Conmfigurations...

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked after removing the `target` folder

Comment: or the build folder.

Answer (score 4):

For eclipse IDE,

Please follow the below steps -

1. Right Click on "Project" -> "properties"
2. Click on "Java Compiler"
3. Check "Enable Project Specific Setting"
4. Correct the "compiler compilation level" ( ref pic is attached )
5. If needed, verify and correct java build path for the project as well.

[image: Eclipse Project Properties Window]

Comment: The Question is for intellij ide

Comment: I have tried this solution but somehow it is getting set back to java 17 , i want to run my projecct with java 15 also, in java  buildpath , it is picking 17

Comment: I was having the same issue in Eclipse IDE, thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 4):

1. File
2. Settings
3. Build, Execution, Deployment:
4. Compiler
5. Java Compiler
6. in **Project bytecode version** choose 8

[image: Intellij Project bytecode version 8]

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, I got this error when trying to run SoapUI. Installing the latest OpenJDK JRE package fixed the issue, for example with Ubuntu: `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre`.

I found this question on a search engine, so maybe it will help other people.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you compiled the code with Java 13 (class file 57), and the java runtime is set to Java 8 (class file 52).

Assuming you have the [JRE 13 installed](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GDRAD/java.htm#BGBFHBEA) in your local system, you could change your runtime from 52 to 57.
That you can do with the plugin **Choose Runtime**. To install it go to *File/Settings/Plugins*.

[image]

Once installed go to *Help/Find Action*, type "runtime" and select the JRE 13 from the dropdown menu.

[image]

Comment: This rendered the IntelliJ IDE unusable.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this issue When I recently upgraded my IntelliJ version to `2020.3`. I had to **disable a plugin** to solve this issue. The name of the plugin is `Thrift Support`.

Steps to disable the plugin is following:

1. Open the Preferences of IntelliJ. You can do so by clicking on `Command + ,` in mac.
2. Navigate to `plugins`.
3. Search for the `Thrift Support` plugin in the search window. Click on the tick box icon to deselect it.
4. Click on the Apply icon.
5. See this image for reference
   [image: Disable_Thrift_support_plugin]

For more detail please refer to this link [java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError 2020.3 version intellij](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-256900). I found this comment in the above link which has worked for me.

> bin zhao commented 31 Dec 2020 08:00
> @Lejia Chen @Tobias Schulmann Workflow My IDEA3.X didn't installed Erlang plugin, I disabled Thrift Support 1.4.0 and it worked. Both IDEA 3.0 and 3.1 have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

For IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3

After updating Module SDK to openjdk-17, it worked for me.
openjdk version "1.8.0_272"

Menu *File* → *Project Structure* → *Modules (Project Settings)* → *Module SDK* (select openjdk-17).
If openjdk-17 is not there, then from the dropdown, select *Add SDK* → *Download JDK* and add openjdk-17.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Android Studio.
I fixed it by updating Gradle to 6.5, and Gradle plugin to 4.11.