# Why can't run jar file from Desktop even though I can do it perfectly well from IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I created a jar file at the end of my project. I build it with IntelliJ and inside it, the file runs smoothly. But the moment I try and execute it from the Desktop, I get nothing. Zero response.
If I try to open it from the command line I get this message:

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

So I figured - I need to install separate JRE. Originally I thought it came along with my JDK but apparently it did not. So I installed JRE in the same Java folder I have my JDK. I run the program again, and now I get this error...

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/javafx/main/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
>
> > at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
> >
> > at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
> >
> > at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
> >
> > at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
> >
> > at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
> >
> > at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
> >
> > at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
> >
> > at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> >
> > at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
> >
> > at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> >
> > at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> >
> > at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
> >
> > at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

I do not understand why it has a problem with my installation. The file was downloaded from Oracle, I didn't even change default destination folder.

I am currently using JDK 13.0.1 and JRE 1.8.0_231

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58125957/104891.

Comment: No, I already uninstalled JRE completely so the only thing my PATH is pointing is JDK 13. And I get this message again: Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application...

Comment: Refer to https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ for the instructions how to set up your environment for building and running JavaFX applications.