# IntelliJ keep showing "openjdk version "15.0.2" when I change the project language level to 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Why the java version is 15.0.2?

[image: Project language level]

[image: language level]

[image: version]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you see version 15.0.2? If it's Terminal tool window, `java` executable is running from the first available directory in your system `PATH` environment variable. Project settings do not affect Terminal.

Comment: Hi CrazyCoder, yes I saw that from Terminal when I type "java -version"

Comment: @Alex as already explained in my answer, Terminal will use `java.exe` from `PATH`. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58125957/104891) for more details how you can adjust it so that different Java version is used by default in your system.

Comment: So as long as I change the language level to 8, it should be 8, is that correct?

Comment: @Alex No, IDE project settings do not have any effect on the Terminal. The only way to change which `java.exe` is called from the Terminal is via the OS `PATH` environment.

Comment: @ CrazyCoder I changed it to 1.8 after I remove 15 from that path! Thanks