# "main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime", Unsure of what the issue is

Tags: path

I was trying to compile and run a java file using command prompt, first used "javac main.java" then ran the class file with "java main"

Upon running the class file, I'm hit with an error:

> "Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
> try again Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: main has been compiled by a
> more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0),
> this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions
> up to 52.0"

I then found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58125830/has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-java-runtime-class-file-versi) possible solution, and updated my User Variables "Path" to jdk17.0.1\bin, and my System Variables "Path" to jre1.8.0_311\bin. I was a bit confused on which Path I was to updated/change so I just updated both...? Not sure if this was the correct thing to do.

In addition, both java -version and javac -version output the latest version "17.0.1" and "jre1.8.0_311".
java -version and javac -version :

[image]

Error Message :

[image]

What confuses me is that running code in eclipse works fine, so I'm not quite sure that it's an issue with Path so I'm not sure what the issue is.