# javac in terminal when java was installed with intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javac

I have installed Java directly in IntelliJ on my new laptop (Oracle openjdk-17) and it doesn't recognize javac.

I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or) but there is no `javac.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`, only `java.exe`, `javaw.exe` and `javaws.exe`. There is a `javac.exe` in `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2\jbr\bin` but it doesn't work when I add it to the Path. Should I install an additional version of jdk.17 outside of IntelliJ to make it work?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58125957/104891. You need to install standalone JDK and javac will be in the bin directory of it, add bin directory of the JDK to PATH and reboot. It's not recommended to use JetBrains Runtime for development, it's for running the IDE itself.

Comment: I don't think I'm using JetBrains Runtime, I'm using https://i.imgur.com/bqpC8qP.png (I've clicked on download jdk). Is this what you call standalone JDK?

Comment: To use this JDK in Terminal you would need to add `c:\Users\<user>\.jdks\openjdk-17.0.2\bin` to `PATH` and reboot. The actual path may be different depending on the JDK version/vendor you installed.

Comment: It worked!!!! I would've never found it without your help, appreciate it!

Comment: So I basically don't really need a standalone JDK right?

Comment: If you are working in IntelliJ IDEA only and don't plan to use this JDK in the system terminal, these steps are optional.