# jaxb2-maven-plugin:3.1.0:xjc Java 8 - Java 11 Migration Issues

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am currently working on java 11 migration project where jaxb2-maven-plugin has been used for XJC task. Post migration to JDK 11 version, I am getting below mentioned errors.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:3.1.0:xjc (xjc) on project test: Execution xjc of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:3.1.0:xjc failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executi
ng org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:3.1.0:xjc: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/glassfish/jaxb/core/api/ErrorListener has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this vers
ion of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:3.1.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/org/codehaus/mojo/jaxb2-maven-plugin/3.1.0/jaxb2-maven-plugin-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.1.1/jakarta.activation-api-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/4.0.0/jaxb-core-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/org/eclipse/angus/angus-activation/1.0.0/angus-activation-1.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/4.0.0/txw2-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/4.0.2/jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/3.0.0/jaxb-xjc-3.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/3.0.0/jaxb-core-3.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/com/sun/activation/jakarta.activation/2.0.0/jakarta.activation-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-jxc/3.0.0/jaxb-jxc-3.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/3.0.0/jaxb-impl-3.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0.1/qdox-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.11.1/plexus-compiler-api-2.11.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.1.0/plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/proj/$%7Benv.M2_REPO%7D/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/4.0.0/istack-commons-runtime-4.0.0.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

Below is my pom.xml,

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>${mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
      <version>${jms-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      <version>${jaxws-rt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>policy</artifactId>
      <version>${policy.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.gmbal</groupId>
      <artifactId>gmbal-api-only</artifactId>
      <version>${gmbal-api-only.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.ha</groupId>
      <artifactId>ha-api</artifactId>
      <version>${ha-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/Test.xsd</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

I have added necessary dependencies like jakarta.annotation-api, jakarta.xml.bind-api, etc., as per java 11 requirements. But still not able to fix the issues. Do you have any suggested fix for this ? Thank in Advance.

Comment: Did you try a spring boot starter?

Comment: It looks `ion of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0` you are using JDK8 instead of JDK11....

Comment: It seems your build itself is still running on Java 8, you should switch that over to Java 11 as well. Theoretically you *could* build a later release when Maven is running on Java 8 (by forking the compiler & similar things), but it'll just cause many more problems. It's much simpler to just run the build on at least the minimum target version.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to compile something using java 11 but your project is running on java 8

[reference with further explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58125830/has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-java-runtime-class-file-versi)