# JavaFX maven samples for CLI and IDE, what is the difference?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

When I run the getting started example:
https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/HelloFX/Maven from the command line (OpenJDK 11, Maven 3.6.3) everything runs fine. When I open the same project in IntelliJ there is an error:

```
Error:(1, 26) java: cannot access javafx.application.Application bad class file: C:\Users\xxxxx\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\13\javafx-graphics-13-win.jar(javafx/application/Application.class)
class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

The Maven example in the IDE subfolder https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Modular/Maven/hellofx runs fine regardless of running from IntelliJ or the command line.

Any ideas why this is? For my own projects I do not want separate versions for the command line and IDE.

Comment: Your IntelliJ project most likely is configured to run and build Java 8 (Class version 52).

Comment: I would expect both examples to fail in the IDE if this was the correct answer. But I went back in and checked to make sure OpenJDK is the default JDK and is selected for both examples.

Comment: The second example defines a compiler release (11) in the pom.xml which forces the maven compiler plugin to build for Java 11 (afaik) - the first one doesn't. 

If you try to copy this setting to the first example, I guess it might work there as well.

Comment: I tried that before posting the question. Did not work. But it would explain why only one example works..

Comment: What are JDK and language level settings for the first and for the second project in IntelliJ IDEA? Please post the same screenshots as you see in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891 .

Comment: Hello, thank you for having a look. I don't think this is in any way an IntelliJ settings problem. I have only one JDK installed: OpenJDK 11. I am happy to look up any specific settings you want to see. If anyone is able to clone the helloFX samples and compile/debug/run them right out of IntelliJ that would be good to know.

It looks like JavaFX is so fragile that it requires a carefully tuned environment to build/run.