# how can i get eror while run edutools program in intellij idea

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, installation, terminal

so I use software IntelliJ idea on my OS, and I install some program on IntelliJ idea plugins the is `edutools`, while I run a program I get an error and the problem of error is I use `java` version

```
OpenJDK 13.0.2 2020-01-14
```

and I already followed the requirement for run some `edutools` program on IntelliJ idea, I use  `Gradle 5.5.1`, why I get an error, and this is my error screenshot on IntelliJ idea :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeesV.png)

Comment: It looks like the project is set to use some older JDK version. Try updating project/module and Gradle JDK to a more recent one. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891 for the relevant screenshots where JDK / language levels can be changed. Gradle JDK can be changed here: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Gradle JVM: https://i.imgur.com/3vqYo2t.png .

Comment: but if I red in this page: https://github.com/exercism/support/issues/73, I was already following the step for complete my configuration in IntelliJ idea.