# java: error: release version 17 not supported

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently updated to Intellij 2021.1. However, whenever I try to run my program, I get:

java: error: release version 17 not supported

I have tried snooping around for other answers, and have found none. It appears my sdk is version 16, if that helps.

Comment: The error message should be clearer. It could say "release version 17 not supported by Maven Runner" or "…not supported by module language level" or "…conflicts with maven property 'maven.compiler.target' or something like that. Incomplete error messages are a pet peeve of mine.

Answer (score 48):

There is one more place worth checking -> Java Compiler settings

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Settings]

Comment: This solved my problem (because IntelliJ had automatically, inexplicably created per-module bytecode version settings). The degree to which IntelliJ has made simple things an exercise in pain is really, really, really frustrating.

Answer (score 32):

I had the same problem. What helped in my case is the following. In IntelliJ IDEA I opened `File -> Project structure` and then clicked `Modules` and changed the `Language level` to 17. Then I was able to run my code without problems.

[image: Project structure window]

Comment: Same with me, selected "JDK Default"

Comment: Worked for me. +1 Vote. But this is horrendous. Rebuild should actually rebuild everything. Thanks a lot for sharing it though.

Comment: This answer, is solution to the following error too: java: error: release version 20 not supported too.
I set the language level to 17. Installed Jdk by Intellij is 18.

Answer (score 17):

1. Check that a JDK 17 is available at File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> "SDKS"
   [image: File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> "SDKS"]
2. Select the 17 JDK at File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> "Project"
   [image: File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> "Project"]
3. File -> Invalidate Caches... -> (leave defaults) -> "Invalidate and Restart"
4. Do "Build" -> "Rebuild Project"

Comment: For me, Step (2) was missing, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

This issue happened to me while upgrading to Java 17, I solved it by configuring the new SDK in project structure and invalidate the caches : File --> invalidate caches --> default selection and restart.

Comment: Along with making sure everything points to the version of the jdk you want to use (all over Intellij), this answer is the secret sauce.

Answer (score 9):

I have faced the same error while trying to use version 16.This is because the new version you are trying to use is unstable.

1. you have to uninstall the version 17  go to:  **file** -> **project
   structure** -> **SDKs** .delete sdk 17 by right clicking on it and
   then delete.
   [right click on highlighted version(in your case its 17)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE9oQ.png)
2. now you have to change project sdk go to: **file** -> **project
   structure** -> **project** . select the previous version which use
   to work for you , in my case its **15 java version "15.0.2"**.  set
   project language level to default (**SDK default(15-Text blocks)**)

   [changing project sdk and project language level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5DCY.png)
3. the last part is to change the project configuration sdk go to your
   navigation bar where you debug your project then select **edit
   configurations** . select the sdk 16 for your project (in my case
   its 15)
   [to change the project configuration sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwiIo.png)

Answer (score 9):

1. file => setting => Build,Execution,Deployment => Java Compiler
2. change Target bytcode version  to your current version of project.[image]

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had to change the JAVA_HOME and the Path system environment variable to point to Java 17 (I used Amazon Corretto) as well in addition to updating Language Level and SDK for Project. My modules used inheritedJdk from Project itself. Java Compiler version was also 17.

Comment: I had the same problem when my JAVA_HOME was pointing to version 11. Intellij still uses this for maven project under the hood dispite what setting i changed in intellij. Took a while to figure this out ;-)

Comment: `echo $JAVA_HOME` told me this was the case. I forgot I was using jenv. So just did a `jenv local 17` and it's good now.

Answer (score 4):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891) for the relevant screenshots. Make sure all the source/target levels are configured correctly in all the dialogs. It may be a typo somewhere and 17 is used instead of 1.7 (Java 7).

Inspect `.idea/misc.xml` file in the project directory, make sure it specifies the correct versions. See also the language levels specified in `*.iml` module files and in `.idea/compiler.xml` file.

Answer (score 4):

There are two actions to take:

1. Go to `File` -> `Project structure` -> `Modules` and changed the Language level to 17
2. Go to `IntelliJ IDEA` -> `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Compiler` -> `Java Compiler`. Change your module's `Target bytecode version version` to 17.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, updating `.idea/misc.xml` didn't help.
I was upgrading from Intellij 2020.2 -> Intellij 2020.4 -> Intellij 2020.1.1.
Ended up with a reset: `File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings...`

Answer (score 2):

Your error is likely from IntelliJ attempting to call a Java 17 parser for compliance with Java 17 syntax (regardless of the SDK type) and there is no Java 17 JDK installed to perform the syntax checking with. You have 2 options.

Change 'Language Level' (Project Settings / Project in the Module Settings available from context window - right click - in the project window) to match your current SDK (ignoring possible language conflicts with more recent versions)

Download a Java 17 JDK to perform parsing with. That is in Platform Settings/SDKs in the same context menu, select '+', select 'Download JDK', then download and install a Java 17 version.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. I went to Project Settings, clicked on Build, Execution, and Deployment, clicked on Java, clicked on Java Compiler, then changed the Java version (Target bytecode version) to 11.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the steps like changing the "Target bytecode version" and "Project bytecode version" and "project language level" but none got worked out. finally I fixed it by upgrading the JDK version from 1.8 to the latest version jdk-20.

Note: Don't forget to change the JAVA_HOME path post upgrading the JDK :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I was using the default Ant run. When I switched the project to maven with the maven-compiler-plugin with java version set this issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this I had to change the Ant build setting Execution -> Jun under JDK. For some reason the default was JDK 11, everywhere else I has specified JDK 16. Once I set this to JDK 16 the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

For similar thing happened when upgrading to java 17. I had it changed everywhere else (suggested by other answers) but in the main maven project .iml file there was still reference to openjdk-16. After manually fixing that to "openjdk-17" it started working well

Answer (score 1):

For me these had to match...

1. File | Project Structure | Project | Project SDK
2. File | Project Structure | Modules | Language level
3. IntelliJ Idea | Preferences | Build, Exec... | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | JDK for importer
4. system.properties (file) java.runtime.version=
5. pom.xml - <java.version>

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was to download Java version 17. You can do this by navigating to File - Project Structure - SDKs and clicking the + button under the Classpath [Download button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5ikD.png)

Comment: How is this different from the existing Answers?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by lowering language level

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

for me i spend really lot of time all was configured correctly, but strangely, the pom.xml was ignored, so right click on pom file => maven => unignore project (on all projects and module)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I setup the SDK and Compiler version correctly still I had the same issue.

Finally, after changing the gradle jvm to use java-17, issue got resolved.

I followed below steps :

- Press Ctrl+Alt+S(letter S) to open settings
- Go to Build, Execution and Deployment
- Then go to Build tool
- select gradle
- Change the gradle-jvm to java-17

please refer below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those using maven-compiler-plugin, adding version in plugin config solves the problem

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
      ...
     </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from Java 8/11 to Java 17:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
  <jdk.version>1.17</jdk.version>
  ....
```

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.11.0</version>
    <configuration>
       <source>${jdk.version}</source>
       <target>${jdk.version}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

just go to environment variables and change tha path to jdk 17 thats it