# JavaFx Project not be able to build after downgrade to jdk11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, build, virtual-machine

Here i changed jdk version of project, from 15 to 11,
But now i got next error message:

> java: error: release version 15 not supported

Attempts:

- Changed VM option:

> --module-path C:\Projects\Java-Todo-List\lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

- Download & add jdbc 8.0.25 & javafx 11.0.2

[image: Here screen]

### Source code

https://github.com/IsElxan/Java-Todo-List/tree/develop

---

P.s. Please, treat with understanding, cause i am still studying.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891 for the relevant screenshots, make sure source/target versions are set to 11 or lower.

Comment: Thanks for the tip !!!