# printf not working as it did in a video

Tags: java, printf

My first class...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MethodsANDInstances16A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        MethodsANDInstances16B methObject = new MethodsANDInstances16B();
        System.out.println("Enter name of first girlfriend or good friend here: ");
        String temp = input.nextLine();
        methObject.setName(temp);
        methObject.saying();
    }
}
```

My second class...

```
public class MethodsANDInstances16B {
    private String girlName;
    public void setName(String name){
        girlName = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return girlName;
    }
    public void saying(){
        System.out.printf("Your first girlfriend or good friend was %s", getName());
    }
}
```

I just watched a Tutorial on YouTube with basically the exact same code... and yet the printf statement doesn't work for me... but it does in the video I watched. I heard I need to change Settings in Eclipse (IDE I'm using), but I'm not sure?

This is the error I'm getting when I run it...

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

    at MethodsANDInstances16B.saying(MethodsANDInstances16B.java:11)
    at MethodsANDInstances16A.main(MethodsANDInstances16A.java:10)"
```

Thank you.

Comment: how does it not work?

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Whats your output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a compilation errors with a simple printf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774428/why-am-i-getting-a-compilation-errors-with-a-simple-printf)

Comment: What version of Java and what JDK are you using?

Comment: Yes, it required a change in Java Compiler settings. I used the link in the comment above.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide Locale.

```
public PrintStream printf(Locale, String, Object... args)
```

so use it like.

```
System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH, "Girlfriend or what not was %s", getName())
```

Comment: The method `printf(String,Object...)` has been there since Java 1.5 so no you shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29

Comment: Your point being? That confirms what I just said: `public PrintStream printf(String format,Object... args)` is right there.

Comment: It simply points i'm quite accurate with the answer as well. Why so aggressive? Hard day?

Comment: I apologize if I sounded aggressive. My point is that from JDK 1.5 the method signature `printf(String,Object...)` has been available. As far as I can tell, there was no `printf` at all in 1.4 so your answer does not address the question.