# Java printf gives "change type to Object" error

Tags: java, eclipse

For some reason, in Eclipse, I get the error "change type of 'i' to 'Object[]'" for the "format" here:

```
int i = 461012;
System.out.format("The value of i is: %d%n", i);
```

I experience this error with JDK 7 and 8 (I tried reinstalling both in turn, and I tried the latest eclipse download, just to be safe).

I'm very confused as to why I can't use an int here.  This example comes directly from the Oracle documentation for format.  printf gives the same error.

Something so simple should be robust and reliable, one would think.

ON EDIT:

Sorry, here's the entire code that doesn't work for me.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 461012;
        System.out.format("The value of i is: %d%n", i);

    }

}
```

And here's exactly what I see in Eclipse when I hover over "format" with the mouse:

> The method format(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String, int)
>
> 1 quick fix available:
>
> Change type of 'i' to 'Object[]'.

Does that help?

Comment: Please print the exact and entire error message, and the exact code that you're using. I suspect that the problem exists in code that we're not seeing.

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. Can you post your entire code an error message. (Sorry, I accidentaly made this an answer).

Comment: I don't believe this doesn't work until you post the full stack trace and code you're using

Comment: The variable `foo` doesnt appear anywhere in the code youve posted

Comment: Works fine here.  You clearly aren't showing us the actual code that fails, and without the code and the actual error message (copy/pasted, not paraphrased) we can't help you.

Comment: Thanks.  I edited my question to include the full code that doesn't work.

Comment: What version of Java are you targeting?

Comment: It works fine on my local machine

Comment: I'm terribly sorry.  I changed the compiler from 1.4 to 1.5 and it works now.  Why did that matter?

Comment: @user3483276 Because 1.4 had a different method `format` in `java.lang.System`, that's why I asked.

Comment: Why are you targeting Java 5 while running 7 and/or 8?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm obviously very naive at all this.  I'm learning.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is that the you Java compliance level set to 1.4. I think it is very probable that this is causing the observed error. Printf didn't exist in Java 1.4

Check that the Compiler compliance level is set to at least 1.5 for your project.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774428/why-am-i-getting-a-compilation-errors-with-a-simple-printf) shows how to change compliance level in Eclipse

Comment: Did this help? If not there might be some other problem with Eclipse. Try running in console