# printf concatenating string with method call

Tags: java, format, printf

Why won't this printf statement work with a method call? I would like to format the roundoff errors from the BMI math calculation.

```
System.out.printf("Your BMI is: %10.2f\n", calcBMI(user_AGE,user_WEIGHT,user_HEIGHT));


    public static double calcBMI(int age, double weight, double height){
//        Calculate BMI by dividing weight in pounds (lbs) by height in inches (in)
//          squared and multiplying by a conversion factor of 703.
//        BMI formula: weight (lb) / [height (in)]2 x 703

//        preconditions: ****
        double BMI = weight / Math.pow( height,2)*703;
        return BMI;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error log?

Comment: @JoelMin cannot resolve printf `Error:(23, 19) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method printf(java.lang.String,double)
  location: variable out of type java.io.PrintStream`

Comment: Can I have a look at your calBMI code? seems like it is not returning a proper double value

Comment: @JoelMin I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the exact same code you have and it worked fine without errors. Hence I suppose it could be a Compiler Compliance issue. Please try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774428/why-am-i-getting-a-compilation-errors-with-a-simple-printf) link and see how it goes. Basically it is about setting your compiler compliance level above 16.