# Java and printf

Tags: java

The code is having some problem with class 2 line 12. Kindly help .
The code is in the image.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class first{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
        pro nc = new pro();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of your first true crush");
        String temp = b.nextLine();
        nc.setname(temp);
        nc.etc();
    }
}

public class pro{
    private String gname;
    public String getName() {
        return gname;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.gname = name;
    }
    public void etc(){
        System.out.printf("The name of your true crush was %s",getName());
    }        
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to post code instead of screenshots.

Comment: Additionally, "having some problem" doesn't describe the problem clearly. Please give a complete description of the error, within the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a compilation errors with a simple printf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774428/why-am-i-getting-a-compilation-errors-with-a-simple-printf)

Comment: Aren't we supposed to use `System.out.format` now?

Comment: The problem is not solved yet!! Still having the same issue!

Answer (score 3):

In class 2 you have not specified the location of the function in System.out.printf(). You should use the this keyword and re-write the function as

```
public class pro {
  private String name;

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }
  public void etc(){
      System.out.printf("The carp is %s",this.getName());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

there is no problem with this

```
I AM USING NETBEANS IDE.



/*

    ///

public class pro {
private String gname;

    public String getname() {
        return gname;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        gname = name;
    }
    public void etc(){
        System.out.printf("Tht name is %s",getname());
    }
}

/////////

    import java.util.Scanner;

        public class first {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner b= new Scanner(System.in);
        pro nc = new pro();
        System.out.println("enter the name");
        String temp = b.nextLine();
        nc.setname(temp);
        nc.etc();
    }
}



/////////

*/
```

Recheck this.

I have not changed your code, just typed it.
And yes I agree with Arc676 that people should post the code.

Comment: Actually I have tried posting the code directly... But it just reports some kind of problem everytime

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem on netbeans.
You can try to use `System.out.format` instead of `System.out.printf`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class first{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
        pro nc = new pro();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of your first true crush");
        String temp = b.nextLine();
        nc.setname(temp);
        nc.etc();
    }
}
public static class pro{
    private String gname;
    public String getName() {
        return gname;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.gname = name;
    }
    public void etc(){
        System.out.format("The name of your true crush was %s", getName()); 
    }        
}
```