# Java system.out.format wants Object[] Array instead of simple Variables?

Tags: java, format, printf

I just wanted to test something with Javas printf method. Now its been a while since I last used this, so maybe this is now normal behaviour.

This code is an example taken from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html and Wikipedia.

The thing is, it wont run.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TestPrintf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.printf("%s, %s", "Hello", "World!");

           // Writes a formatted string to System.out.
           System.out.format("Local time: %tT", Calendar.getInstance());
           // -> "Local time: 13:34:18"


    }

}
```

Leads to

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The method printf(Locale, String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)
The method format(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, Calendar)

at TestPrintf.main(TestPrintf.java:7)
```

I am using Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) on Ubuntu with Java version 1.8.0_74.

I know it used to work this way, but now I have to supply an array with the variables? What if I want to format a mix of strings and integers? An Object[] with mixed types cant really be required now can it?

Some insight why this is required/was changed would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the Java compiler version and source compatibility you have set... Basically Java is not able to recognize varargs in your case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to check that the compiler compliance level is set to 1.5 or higher in your project.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774428/why-am-i-getting-a-compilation-errors-with-a-simple-printf) question for an explanation on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, even though it WAS set to 1.8 and I definitely didnt change a setting, it now works after I checked the compiler compliance level (where it 100% already said 1.8) and hit apply.