# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation error: The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream i

Tags: java

I am new to java programming

I run the following code

```
public class tuna {
    private String girlName;
    public void setName(String name){
        girlName = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return girlName;
    }

    public void saying(){
        String name = getName();
        System.out.printf("Your first gf was %s",name);
    }
}
```

It shows the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
```

Comment: There is no main method in your class.

Comment: @Adya main method is in another class file

Comment: Use System.out.println

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774428/the-method-printfstring-object-in-the-type-printstream-is-not-applicable-fo

Comment: @ Amit Bera I am using eclipse

Comment: I believe this you are facing the issue as you may have set java compiler below `1.5` in eclipse. To configure it to proper version please visit the link provided by @SagarRohankar.