# Eclipse Java project - unable to get images

Tags: java

I've created a sub-folder to hold 2 images, but having errors when using getResource().
Also, error occurs in line 29 String.format(...);
Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some code? , We are not wizards we need code to see what's the problem with it buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code in Gui.java file in line 16 you wrote "getResource(./images/youtube.png)"
But in your images folder there is no image named youtube.png.
That's why it get a null pointer exception in line 16

Comment: and also check this link for string error [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701532/string-format-is-not-working)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did try several times delete and recreate the files and folder. End up accidentally load a wrong image and didn't notice.